# nodejs does not read JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

This must be something very obvious but I spent enough time on it:

Node express gets a JSON object that was set in the browser.
the object name is dddd.

when I:

```
console.log(req.params.dddd);
```

I get:

```
{"email":"abc@def.com"}
```

which is correctly what I set to node.js

but when I:

```
console.log(req.params.dddd.email);
```

I get `undefined`...

I must be missing the point on this one. Than you to anyone helping

Comment: @OliverBorchert why would that make a difference? It's exactly equivalent to `console.log(req.params.dddd.email)`.

Comment: Sending JSON data using url params is not a very good design. You should use request body instead, or at least query string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you get a string and you mistakenly think it's a JSON.
try JSON.parse before.

```
var obj = JSON.parse( req.params.dddd);
console.log(obj.email)
```

Comment: `[...]JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format[...]` and is delivered as string or buffer. That is why you need use `JSON.parse`  which returns a JavaScript object that has the structure described by the JSON-data.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    var obj = JSON.parse( req.params.dddd);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("parsing error!!!")
}
console.log(obj.email)
```

Always use `try ... catch` block while using `JSON.parse` method.